# ActiveAndroid: Date columns not created

Tags: android, sqlite, date, activeandroid

I am trying to store a `Person` object with ActiveAndroid. I set the birthdate like this: `person.setBirthdate(new java.sql.Date((new Date()).getTime()));`. After assigning all data i am calling `person.save();`.

I get a list of all persons from the database with this command: `new Select().from(Person.class).execute();`

If I do not close the app everything works fine (birthdate is always returned correctly from the database). However, when I close the app completely and then restart it, the birthdate is always null. All other fields (first name, last name etc.) are correct.

I really don't know why this is happening and would appreciate some help!

**EDIT**: After taking a closer look at my database I found out that the birthdate-column is not created. I am still not sure why the data is available when not closing the app though.

**Second EDIT**: I added a new column (a string) which is saved to the database and works just fine. So the problem is not an outdated database. All columns but the date column get created.

I also changed the date datatype to a string. The birthdate was then saved. Changing it back to a Date datatype resulted in the original problem again. Really weird... Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: why u use java.sql.Date insteed java.util.Date?

Comment: did u solve the problem?

Comment: I was using JodaTime's `DateTime` as my column field type and it was silently not creating the column in the SQLIte database. You have to create a custom TypeSerializer if you're going to do this. See this for more info: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/516

Comment: @LunaVulpo Sorry I missed your comment. No, I unfortunately could not solve the problem back then :/

Answer (score 3):

It should be some caching problem.
for saving Date try to use [type serializer](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers). it is so easy just read [this page](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers).

Comment: have you tried to update your schema or unistall and reinstalling your app again?

Comment: I updated my schema (if that means increasing the database version number) and reinstalled the app, but still not working...

Comment: You answer is not correct at all. Date is serialized by AA automatically according to https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActiveAndroid-Guide